# Laravel image upload validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to validate uploaded files using laravel validation but am having issues.

Here is my code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'image' =>'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif',

        ]);

        $avatar = $request->file('image');

        $fileName = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('uploads/avatar/' . $fileName));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $fileName;
        $user->save();
```

The issue is when I use a bmp file, I get this error:
[Gd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV7KG.png)

I am using the Intervention image package.  I would rather not switch to the imagick driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you must declare BMP mime in your image array. Something like this: 'image' =>'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp',

Comment: Which intervention image package version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Intervention package code, you can see two implementations to the **processBmp** function:

Intervention/Image/Gd/Encoder.php:

```
protected function processBmp()
{
    throw new \Intervention\Image\Exception\NotSupportedException(
        "BMP format is not supported by Gd Driver."
    );
}
```

Intervention/Image/Imagick/Encoder.php:

```
protected function processBmp()
{
    $format = 'bmp';
    $compression = \Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED;
    $imagick = $this->image->getCore();
    $imagick->setFormat($format);
    $imagick->setImageFormat($format);
    $imagick->setCompression($compression);
    $imagick->setImageCompression($compression);
    return $imagick->getImagesBlob();
}
```

So I think it's safe to say that you can't do it with the GD driver, only with imagick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `"intervention/image": "~2"` or change your driver to Imagick. It is a known issue that GD does not natively support BMP. You can check the [issue page on github](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/200) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don`t use Laravel custom rule for image [image](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-image)?

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'image' =>'image',

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this solution will fix your error, please try with below logic

```
 public function postUpload(Request $request)
    {

    $input = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
      'uploadFile' => 'image|max:8000'
    );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails())
    {
      return array(
          'validation_failed' => true,
          'errors'            => $validation->errors()->toArray()
      );
    }

    $file = $request->uploadFile;
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/img';

    // Get real extension according to mime type
    $ext = $file->extension();
    // Hash processed file name, including the real extension
        $hashname           = date('H.i.s').'-'.md5($request->_token).'.'.$ext;
        $upload_success     = $request->uploadFile->storeAs($destinationPath, $hashname);


        Image::configure(array('driver' => 'imagick'));
        $img = Image::make(storage_path() . '/app/uploads/img/' . $hashname);
        $img->resize(230, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $img->save(storage_path() . '/app/uploads/lowres/' .$hashname ,80);

        $user_image = new User_images();
        $user_image->id_user = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_image->handler = $hashname;
        $user_image->save();


        return array('status' => 'success','message'=> 'Image has been uploaded successfully','file_path'=>'/uploads/'.$hashname);
```